# How to strip "#" from item inside list?

Tags: python, list, strip

My list is,

```
a=["# abc" ,"def","ghi" ,"jkl #"]
```

and i want my output be like this,

```
a=["abc","def","ghi","jkl"]
```

I tried this code,but I am not able to strip "#"

```
for item in a:
    if any("#" in item):
        item.strip("#")
```

How to strip "#" from item inside list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = [b.replace('#', '') for b in a]
```

or if you want the spaces to go as well

```
a = [b.replace('#', '').replace(' ', '') for b in a]
```

Comment: What if the list was `['# ab cd e', etc]`

Comment: I gave an answer to the question he asked, not what-if

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. Firstly, the use of `any()` here is not needed. You can just do `if "#" in item:`
2. Instead of modifying `item` (which will do absolutely nothing), you'll want to append the solution to another list, like so:

---

```
new = []
for item in a:
    if "#" in item:
        new.append(item.strip("#"))
```

Just remember that in python, strings are immutable, so doing `str.strip()` won't modify the string in place.

Also, if you want to get rid of the extra whitespace, then you'll want to add an extra space in your call to strip:

```
new.append(item.strip("# "))
```

And finally, this is where list comprehensions come in handy:

```
[i.strip('# ') for i in a]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.strip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.strip) with `'# '` as argument to remove surrounding `#` and spaces:

```
>>> [x.strip('# ') for x in a]
['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']
```